# Self reference in @expression statement in Julia

Tags: mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

I am still quite new in Julia but I was wondering if there is a way to make a self reference in an @expression statement in JuMP.

For instance I would like to be able to make this statement:

`n = 3
@expression(model_opt, D[i=1:9], i>n ? D[i-n] : i)`

which would define a vector D as follows

`D = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]`

But for the moment Julia just tells me that D is not known

`UndefVarError: D not defined`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Julia, you're in for a ride. No, that is not supported. You can write a `for` loop instead:

```
D = []
n = 3
for i in 1:9
    push!(D, @expression(model_opt, i>n ? D[i-n] : i))
end
```